# language and time (in "arrival")

Tags: time, language

upon seeing the much discussed movie - arrival: how far can one stretch the sapir-whorf hypothesis? could it transcend space and take over time? could a language, however complicated, once learned allow those who speak it to see events that are about to happen (let alone things that'll happen in 3000 years)? if that should work (?) why would the UG not be able to do the same (sometime in the future, following evolution's path)?

Comment: For a more realistic comparison of the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis and the universal grammar see [related question on Linguistics SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14673/sapir-whorf-vs-chomsky)

Answer (score 3):

Linguistic relativity is a thesis that talks about people's *perceptions* of the world. It doesn't do anything to alter the actual structure of the world. The laws of causality are defined by Einstein's relativity and they tell us that nothing can travel faster than the speed of light, and superluminal messaging is what is required for time travel. Linguistic relativity is a thesis that talks about how language influences, or possibly defines people's thought, not how it influences the causal structure of the world. There's no part of the thesis that gives language the power to restructure physics. Information cannot travel at superluminal speeds so people cannot have cognition of events before they happen. If a language develops to a point where somebody perceives themselves as being able to tell the future, that is a completely different thing than that person actually being able to tell the future.